# "Unable to verify integrity of data" while running MR job

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce

I'm running a relatively big MR job using Amazon Elastic Map Reduce.

I ran the job plenty of times on small data sets with no problem.

But when trying to run it on a large dataset I'm getting the following exception:

> Error: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to verify integrity
>   of data download.  Client calculated content length didn't match
>   content length received from Amazon S3.  The data may be corrupt.

I googled it and the only recommendation I got was to set the following:

> System.setProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3.disableGetObjectMD5Validation","true");

That didn't help at all.

I'm using replication 3, 11 M1Large datanodes and 1 M1Medium master node.

Any workaround or known fix for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is a known bug. Or so I've been told by an Amazon employee [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=548359).

It occurs when running on large datasets where an S3 object is bigger than 2GB.

I managed to work around it by moving to Hadoop 2.4.0 and AMI 3.1.0.